# Prolog - artificial intelligence (Lists, lines)

Tags: prolog

I am trying this new type of programming, Prolog.

I want to define a line `line(A,B,C)` with the equation `Ax + By + C = 0` and I want to define a multitude of lines (and it should have the type: multitudine_lines(ListOfLines)` ) :

```
multitude_lines([line(2,3,4),line(1,2,3),line(2,6,7)]).
```

I defined a line, but I do not know how to define  multitude_lines.

I need some help please...

Comment: The problem is not adequately defined. Are you only looking for lines with integer coefficients and coordinates? What do the lines in your "multitude of lines" have in common? Do they all meet a specific condition? I would not categorize this as an artificial intelligence problem.

Comment: The lines can have float coefficients  and coordinates too. No, the lines from multitude of lines do not have something in common.

Comment: Multitude of lines must have as parameter a list of lines. @luker

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, `multitude_lines` should convert the list of "lines" into a list of equations. This program converts each line into an equation:

```
:- initialization(main).
:- set_prolog_flag(double_quotes, chars). 

main :- multitude_lines([line(2,3,4),line(1,2,3),line(2,6,7)],Output),writeln(Output).

multitude_lines([],[]).
multitude_lines([line(A,B,C)|D],[(A*x + B*y + C = 0)|D1]) :-
    multitude_lines(D,D1).
```

This program prints `[2*x+3*y+4=0,1*x+2*y+3=0,2*x+6*y+7=0]`.